# Exception invoking jsConstructor caused by ActiveXImpl

Tags: java, htmlunit

i am having this error while trying to access a page through htmlunit webclient:

Code example:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
    WebClientOptions webClientOptions = webClient.getOptions();
    webClientOptions.setSSLClientCertificate(new URL("File:C:\\Cert.pfx"), "dubqf!$@", "PKCS12");
    webClientOptions.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClientOptions.setSSLTrustStore(new URL("File:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_01\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts"), "changeit", "jks");
    webClientOptions.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClientOptions.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClientOptions.setActiveXNative(true);


    final HtmlPage pg       = webClient.getPage(u);
    HtmlPasswordInput pass  = (HtmlPasswordInput) pg.getElementById("PasswordTxt");
    HtmlTextInput ac        = (HtmlTextInput) pg.getElementById("AgentCode");
    HtmlTextInput oc        = (HtmlTextInput) pg.getElementById("OfficeCode");
    HtmlTextInput ut        = (HtmlTextInput) pg.getElementById("UserTxt");

    ac.click(); ac.type("1058");
    oc.click(); oc.type("07");
    ut.click(); ut.type("gebrane");
    pass.click(); pass.type("gebran.h2");

ScriptResult result = pg.executeJavaScript("__doPostBack('LogInLinkBut','')");
HtmlPage newPage    = (HtmlPage) result.getNewPage();
```

Enclosed exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking jsConstructor
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:181)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:391)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.construct(BaseFunction.java:394)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1591)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:827)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:939)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:836)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:812)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:800)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:354)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:415)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:271)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:293)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:799)
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:756)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
>           at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1039)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:252)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:198)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:271)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:159)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:478)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2135)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:982)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:103)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:949)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:836)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:812)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:800)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:878)
>           at com.softsolutions.subagent.api.model.MainAPIConfiguration$$M$a1d673a.getOgeroContent(MainAPIConfiguration.java:190)
>           at com.softsolutions.subagent.api.model.MainAPIConfiguration$$M$a1d673a.doCompose(MainAPIConfiguration.java:105)
>           at com.softsolutions.subagent.api.model.MainAPIConfiguration$$A$a1d673a.doCompose()
>           at com.softsolutions.subagent.api.model.MainAPIConfiguration.doCompose()
>           at com.softsolutions.common.base.ui.composer.SoftSolComposer.doAfterCompose(SoftSolComposer.java:163)
>           at com.softsolutions.subagent.api.model.MainAPIConfiguration.doAfterCompose()
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.CreateInfo.doAfterCompose(UiEngineImpl.java:2598)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:881)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:826)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:735)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:699)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:442)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:356)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:215)
>           at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:136)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObjectImpl
>           at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject.jsConstructor(ActiveXObject.java:123)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
>           ... 99 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. it appeared that i should change the location of the .dll file for jacob.jar. It was put under web-inf/lib. I moved it to tomcat/bin location and it worked well.